# Why does Perl's strict not let me pass a parameter hash?

Tags: perl, strict

I hava a perl subroutine where i would like to pass parameters as a hash
(the aim is to include a css depending on the parameter 'iconsize').

I am using the call:

```
get_function_bar_begin('iconsize' => '32');
```

for the subroutine get_function_bar_begin:

```
use strict;
...
sub get_function_bar_begin
{
    my $self = shift;
    my %template_params = %{ shift || {} };

    return $self->render_template('global/bars   /tmpl_incl_function_bar_begin.html',%template_params);
}
```

Why does this yield the error message:

**Error executing run mode 'start': undef error - Can't use string ("iconsize") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at CheckBar.pm at line 334**

Am i doing something wrong here?
Is there an other way to submit my data ('iconsize') as a hash?

(i am still new to Perl)

**EDIT: Solution which worked for me**. I didn't change the call, but my function:

```
sub get_function_bar_begin
{
    my $self = shift;
    my $paramref = shift;
    my %params = (ref($paramref) eq 'HASH') ? %$paramref : ();
    my $iconsize = $params{'iconsize'} || '';

    return $self->render_template('global/bars/tmpl_incl_function_bar_begin.html',
        {
            'iconsize'  => $iconsize,
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Your "call" indicates that you're making a function call, but your error and your subroutine indicate that you're making a method call. Which is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using the hash-dereferencing operator ( `%{ }` ) on the first argument of your parameter list. But that argument is *not* a hash reference, it's just the string `'iconsize'`. You can do what you want by one of two ways:

Pass an anonymous hash reference:

```
get_function_bar_begin( { 'iconsize' => '32' } );
```

Or continue to pass a normal list, as you are right now, and change your function accordingly:

```
sub get_function_bar_begin {
    my $self = shift;
    my %template_params = @_;
}
```

Notice in this version that we simply assign the argument list directly to the hash (after extracting `$self`). This works because a list of `name => value` pairs is just syntactic sugar for a normal list.

I prefer the second method, since there's no particularly good reason to construct an anonymous hashref and then dereference it right away.

There's also some good information on how this works in this post: [Object-Oriented Perl constructor syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703046/object-oriented-perl-constructor-syntax/1703112).

Comment: way one still gives me "undef error - Can't use string ("iconsize") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use",
way two gives "Reference found where even-sized list expected at CheckBars.pm line 334"

Comment: Thariama, you're doing things backwards. *Either* use `$self->get_function_bar_begin( { ... } )` and extract the reference with `%{ }` *OR* use `$self->get_function_bar_begin( ... )` and build the hash with `%params = @_`. The errors you're getting suggest you're trying to mix and match both approaches.

Comment: i tried both ways, but found a solution now (see my edited post)

Answer (score 6):

You're violating `strict refs` by trying to use the string `iconsize` as a hash reference.

I think you just want:

```
my( $self, %template_params ) = @_;
```

The first argument will go into `$self` and the rest create the hash by taking pairs of items from the rest of `@_`.

Comment: i still get "Odd number of elements in hash assignment at CheckBars.pm line 333."

Comment: @Thariama: brian's example was for a method, but the way you're calling the function in the actual question was as a function (where there is no `$self` argument).  You should probably read up on `perldoc perlsub` (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html).

Comment: thx brian for your answer - i got two of your books on my desk :)

Comment: @Thariama: Having Brian's books on your desk is good, reading them is better ! :)

Comment: i am - i am, but still new to Perl

Answer (score 4):

**Passing hash with parameters as list**

You need to use `@_` variable instead of `shift`. Like this:

```
my %template_params = @_; ## convert key => value pairs into hash
```

There is different between hashes and references to hash in perl. Then you pass `'iconsize' => '32'` as parameter this means *list* to perl, which can be interpreited as *hash*.

**Passing hash with parameters as hash reference**

But when you try `%{ shift || {} }` perl expect second parameter to be a hash references. In this case you can fix it in following way:

```
get_function_bar_begin({ 'iconsize' => '32' }); ## make anonymous hash for params
```

Comment: i still get "Odd number of elements in hash assignment at CheckBars.pm line 333."

Comment: `$self` is needed only for methods. Remove `my $self = shift;` line if you're calling function as `get_function_bar_begin(...)`. (Methods should be called as `$instance->method_name(...)`, but this is another story)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
get_function_bar_begin('iconsize' => '32');
```

This does not pass a hash *reference*, as you seem to think, but a hash, which appears as a list to the callee. So when you do `%{ shift }`, you're only shifting the key `'iconsize'`, not the entire list. The solution is actually to make the second line of your function simpler:

```
my %template_params = @_;
```

Comment: It doesn't pass a hash at all, it passes a list. All subroutine arguments in Perl are lists.

Comment: @Thariama, $self is passed as a hidden first argument to your function, assuming that it's called through a blessed reference (`$obj->get_function_bar_begin(@args)`. If you're not calling `get_function_bar_begin` through an object, then you shouldn't be shifting `$self` off of `@_`! This might be why you're also getting the error about "Odd number of elements in hash assignment".